# How to loop through a HTMLCollection in an angular app using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, htmlcollection

I'm new to angular, and I'm trying to loop through a html collection so that I can get properties such as id for each element but it does not seem to be working even after get a array representation of the collection as seen on the code below. I'm using typescript to build an angular app. Any work around this? or anything I'm doing wrong?

```
this.customElements = Array.from(
      document.getElementsByClassName('custom-elem')
    );

    this.customElements.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it does not seems to be working" ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a new array from the HTMLCollection. `getElementsByClassName()` function by default returns an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) of all child elements. So the following should work:

```
this.customElements = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-elem');

for (const element in this.customElements) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9amwbq)